# Where to put a helper function in angular's directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a simple directive:

```
angular.module("foo").directive('bar',function(){
    return {
        ...
        template:
            '<div> \
                <div ng-hide="param1.length == 0 && param2...">...</div> \
                <input ng-show="param1.length == 0 && param2..." .../> \
             </div>',
        scope: {
            param1: '=',
            param2: '='
        }
    };
});
```

but there is a duplicated complex logic inside the template so i would like to extract it to a function and just call that function from a template. Where can I put such function and how can I invoke it? Do I have to create a dedicated controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the link function:

```
return {
    ...,
    template: '<div><div ng-hide="foo()">...</div></div>',
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.foo = function() {
            return scope.param1.length == 0 && ...;
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You use declare services to achieve this in angular. From angular docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

> Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together
>   using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and
>   share code across your app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, compact and easy to understand method I use.
First, add a service in your js.

```
app.factory('Helpers', [ function() {
      // Helper service body

        var o = {
        Helpers: []

        };

        // Dummy function with parameter being passed
        o.getFooBar = function(para) {

            var valueIneed = para + " " + "World!";

            return valueIneed;

          };

        // Other helper functions can be added here ...

        // And we return the helper object ...
        return o;

    }]);
```

Then, in your controller, inject your helper object and use any available function with something like the following:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', [

'$scope',
'Helpers',

function($scope, Helpers){

    $scope.sayIt = Helpers.getFooBar("Hello");
    console.log($scope.sayIt);

}]);
```